Sliding frame optimization
I have a challenge regarding optimization of a laser die-cutter. Material is scrolled from left  right through the laser chamber and the laser needs to cut out various shapes on the material. The entire job is longer (L) than the width (W) of the chamber. I can set up the entire job, so that it starts with the rightmost shapes and work towards the left.  I can calculate the time it takes to cut all the shapes and jump between them, so I have the work as a function of position on the material (x) in some sense. I can also make the laser wait between shapes until they are inside the chamber but if a shapes has scrolled out to the left I cannot reverse the direction and that shape is lost -which is unacceptable)
So the question is: How fast can I scroll the material through without losing shapes to the left? It feels very much like convolution but I cannot get my head around it.
